# Pharo: download file in parallel chunks

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I'm trying to download a large file in chunks, with each chunk downloaded in parallel with the others.  All chunks would be combined at the end.

However, from my understanding, Pharo's basic threading interleaves instead of being truly parallel, meaning one chunk has to wait for the previous to finish.

Is there a way to accomplish something like this?

Note: apologies for lack of code.  I had a "working" project, but I don't have access to that code at the moment.

Comment: First you should add the code. Second if you use UDP then you can download it in parallel.  For more see the answer.

Comment: Semaphore is a possibility also (http://onsmalltalk.com/smalltalk-concurrency-playing-with-futures)

Answer (score 2):

> one chunk has to wait for the previous to finish

The key is that with non-blocking sockets you don't have to wait for a chunk to finish. Look for something like `SocketStream>>isDataAvailable` and `SocketStream>>nextAvailable` and read only what is available without blocking.